# Change DB Column Value in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a function where I can accept bids and when I accepted a bid other bids of the same project get a reverse update.

## Explanation

```
bid 1 -> accept = y
[bid 2, bid 3, ....] -> accept = r
```

So far I can only change `bid 1` status but `bid 2, 3...` I'm not sure how to get them.

[image](https://ibb.co/mjsSjU)

[image: one]

**Code**

This is my current code which changes `bid 1` status (accepted column)...

```
public function bidaccepted(Request $request, $id)
{
    $bid = Bid::findOrFail($id);
    $bid->accepted = 'y';
    $bid->save();
}
```

**Blade**

```
<a href="{{route('bidaccepted', $bid->id)}}" class="text-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Accept This Bid</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/bidaccepted/{id}', 'Front\BidChatController@bidaccepted')->name('bidaccepted');
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, not related to your question, I would advice you to follow PSR conventions, bidaccepted should be bidAccepted.

As for your question:

```
public function bidAccepted(Request $request, $id)
{
    $bid = Bid::findOrFail($id);
    $bid->accepted = 'y';
    $bid->save();

    // The part you 
    Bid::where('id', '!=', $id)
       ->where('project_id', $bid->project_id)
       ->update(['accepted' => 'n']);
}
```

I'm not a big fan of the way you chose to represent your data and the project accepted bid and I'm not a big fan of my solution neither :) But as for your question my answer should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like that

In the table migration add a default value for the column accepted as null

When a bid is accepted; update the column for the accepted bids as y, and rest (where accepted = null) is automatically treated as not accepted.

If you want to change the accepted status you have to change the accepted column status of old bid as null and then update the new one as y.

Comment: accepted has default value, is `n`. default of all bids is `n` then one will accept as `y` the rest will reject as `r` :)

Comment: i don't see any benefit here, why you need r if you are doing that for all the rest of the rows.

Comment: This is status ok? N= pending (no action) Y= accepted R = rejected so when one bid is rejected users can't continue discussion etc. I need that r for validating other parts.

Comment: Every single bid has n, one will change to y i need to change the rest of them with n to r

Comment: Ok; you know your application more than any of us. But I have another recommendation if you are using the solution provided in the other answer do use the transaction functionality.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#database-transactions

Comment: I didn't get i well, what benefit it has on my issue? Would you mind explain it a bit?

Comment: It is not related to Laravel, it is related to the solution in the other answer. It is a database rule to use transaction blocks if an update is to be done using more than one query , you can learn a bit more by searching the net. Search database transactions